# Is FSC certification something I should pay attention to?

Tags: forestry

The [Forest Stewardship Council](https://fsc.org/en) (FSC) certification is supposed to be granted to "responsible" producers of timber, but Greenpeace [doesn't](https://www.greenpeace.org/static/planet4-international-stateless/2021/04/b1e486be-greenpeace-international-report-destruction-certified_finaloptimised.pdf) see much difference between certified and non-certified patches of forest in commercial use. Is FSC certification something I should pay attention to?

Comment: I closed this question as opinion-based because each person has their own opinion about whether or not to pay attention to specific organizations. Wikipedia has an excellent summary of [support and criticism for FSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forest_Stewardship_Council#Support_and_criticism_of_FSC_certification). Please consider making this question [on-topic](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) by adding detail about how you're trying to live more sustainably.